# Ruby scope variable

Tags: ruby

Here's the code:

```
class Something
   attr_accessor :x
   def initialize(x)
      @x = x
   end
   def get_x
      x
   end
end

something = Something.new(5)
something.get_x # => 5
```

Why interpreter returns 5 if `x` is just a local variable in `get_x` method? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`attr_accessor :x` adds two methods for you:

```
def x=(val)
  @x = val
end

def x
  @x
end
```

So you don't actually need `get_x` getter if you've added `attr_accessor` method.

**UPD**

So the question is

```
class Something
  attr_accessor :x
  def initialize(x)
    @x = x
  end
  def set_x=(new)
    x = new
  end
end
```

Why won't `x = new` call default `x` setter: because default `x` setter is an instance method so you can call it for an object (Something instance) but not in your class like you try.

Comment: But what if we have another method def set_x(new_x) x = new_x end, why interpreter doesn't assume that is x=(val) method?

Comment: you can write as many setters as you want. `attr_accessor` is just a "helper" it creates two methods for you, but you are free to create as much as you need

Comment: The question is not how to make better, it's compiler trick issue.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't see here any issue.

Comment: Ok, again, class Something has another method def set_x(new_x) x = new_x end. Inside we have a local variable x, but also we have defined method x=(val), why interpreter doesn't treat it as method x=(val)?

Comment: The interpreter is never going to make assumptions like that about your code, and why would you want it to?  You might have a perfectly good reason for adding your own get/set methods.  If the interpreter started playing with those, I can't even imagine what would happen.

Comment: Because `x` is instance method, so it won't trigger it as default setter

Comment: Oh wait now I see what you're saying. If you use 'self.x = new_x' it actually does do that.  This just seems like trying to break the interpreter. You should always be explicit about what variable/method you want in internal code.

Comment: @muffinista Maybe not _always_. Specifically, because a) `self` can be omitted in calls within the scope, and b) `foo = x` could be interpreted as either invoking the `foo=` method and passing `x` or setting a local variable `foo` to `x`, you should specify `self` when attempting to invoke a setter method.

Comment: The other interesting edge case can be seen as the interpreter guesses if you're accessing a local variable or invoking a method on yourself. Try this: `def x; "method"; end; p x; x = 42; p x`. The first `x` invokes the method (because no local variable with that name exists), but the second identical `x` reads the local variable. Local variables mask methods in the same scope unless you prefix with `self.`

Answer (score 5):

`x` is also a method.  `attr_accessor :x` adds `x=` and `x` to your class. So, get_x is calling the `x` method, and returning the value for `@x`. see http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/accessors.html for details.

Answer (score 2):

The `attr_accessor` defines a method `x` (and the setter `x=`) which gets called in `get_x`.

```
>> something.methods.grep /^x/
=> [:x, :x=]
```